# Python - Best practices to queue / dequeue threads

Tags: python, multithreading, architecture, queue

I have a queue which can contain max 4 queued objects. These objects are threads running web service requests. The thread part is OK.
I have followed many tutorials which talk about consumer and producer threads used to fill in and out the queue object.
My question is about the consumer part. In all these tutorials and regarding the python doc, the only way I have found to pile out objects from the queue is :

```
while len(requltArray) < amountOfThreads:
    thread = q.get(True)
    thread.join()
```

Imagine the q.get(True) piles out a thread with an invalid web service request. And imagine this thread have to wait for urllib timeout to end. My consumer will be blocked for some seconds. As my queue is limited to 4 threads and maybe the 3 others have ended yet, I waste time until consumer can continue the pile-outs (and producer can fill the queue).

Is there any way or well-known design pattern to avoid this waste of time ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm confused about your goal here - do you want to clean up the three finished threads, and then wait on the 4th?  Or are you asking how you can kill one if it takes longer than a certain time to finish?  If it's the former, [the doc](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) has a good answer - call `join(1.0)` (that is, with a timeout of 1 second here), followed by `is_alive()`.  If it's the latter, there is no *easy* way to do that.

Comment: Enqueuing a thread is an odd thing to do.  Most folks have many worker threads reading from a common queue, and enqueue the requests for the worker threads to work on.  Why not follow the design pattern of everyone else and have four threads reading the queue for requests?  Why do it backwards?

Comment: - Nate: In fact it is the first one, thanks for the join(1.0) hint
- S.Lott: Your design pattern seams much more great than mine. I am not so familiar with common design patterns. I will use it. You should post a complete answer to guide beginners (like me)

Comment: @kheraud: "You should post a complete answer to guide beginners".  I don't think I can.  I don't understand what you're trying to do.  I only see the question, which does something odd and incomplete.  Perhaps you should explain what you're producing, what you're consuming and what processing you want to happen.  As a separate question.

Comment: @Nate: Ok, I understand. My real goal is more complex that what I describe in this post. I am working on another thread which describe my goal and the design I choose.
Thanks for your help

Comment: @kheraud: Don't focus on the design you chose.  It seems broken.  Describe your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use [conditions](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#condition-objects)

Imagine you want to put a new thread into your queue but it is full. Then you could wait() for the condition object (pseudo code):

```
condition.acquire()
while not queue.has_free_place():
    condition.wait()
add_new_thread_to_queue()
condition.release()
```

And inside your queued threads you could place something like the following code at the end of execution:

```
condition.acquire()
remove_myself_from_queue()
condition.notify()
condition.release()
```

Comment: Good hint, I didn't know conditions (kind of lock). But I will prefer the recommended design pattern proposed by S.Lott